# AWS Lambda access to RDS outside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

The RDS instance is not on VPC (Classic); it is associated to a security group with allowances to some CIDR/IPs and EC2 security groups.

I want to create a AWS Lambda function that will execute some SQL statements on this database, and also make requests to a EC2 instance that is in the same security group. Is it possible to allow Lambda to access this database?

Comment: Could you please edit your Question to provide more details? Are you saying that you have an Amazon RDS instance that is in a private subnet in a different VPC? Does your AWS Lambda function wish to run some SQL on the RDS database? Any clarification would help us to answer your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Lambda function outside VPC: Set the RDS to "Publicly Accessible" and in the security group allow access from everywhere (because the set of Lambda IPs is not known).

2) Lambda function inside VPC: Allow access to RDS from all IPs in the VPC because the Lambda function will get an IP from the available ones in your VPC. Beware: If the Lambda function is run multiple times in parallel, your VPC may run out of IPs, making your Lambda function fail.

Comment: Note, simply setting up the Lambda to operate inside the VPC will prohibit the Lambda from accessing resources outside the VPC (including other AWS resources such as S3).  In order to allow access to both, follow these instructions, they were a lifesaver.  https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7

Comment: What is the workaround for case 2 (VPC running out of IPs)?

Comment: @ftkg There is not a workaround per se. Your options are to ask AWS for more IPs or move the Lambda function outside of the VPC.

Comment: I will not do option number 2. Especially when I saw the pricing for NAT gateway, and you need one NAT for each AZ. This is a rip off, you expect simple services, why should I pay for every GB just to communicate with other AWS resources.. kinesis, S3, that will be a lot of data which is provisioned.

Comment: Also consider https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lambda-vpc-cold-starts-a-latency-killer-5408323278dd - there is no good solution here if you need to worry about security at all.

Comment: What are the security risks of option 1? Does that mean your database password is your only line of defense?

Comment: @vitale232 Yes, password only

Comment: Another thing with option 1 is that you are making the connection directly to the RDS which will be inefficient. You will need to use RDS Proxy which is only accessible inside the VPC :(



More details explained here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-database-options-for-your-serverless-web-applications/



I am looking into if using the Aurora Serverless Edition will make this easier to use without VPC. NAT Gateway Prices are too restrictive.